# IdentityServer4 configure for Implicit token flow issue with IDX10609: Decryption failed. No Keys tried: token: '[PII is hidden]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, identityserver4

Creating a ASP.NET MVC 5 client for IdentityServer4.

Problem in return Url. 
when hitting client application page, request goes to IdentityServer4 login page and redirect back to MVC client requested page. Problem here, return to blank white page and error capture as, `IDX10609: Decryption failed. No Keys tried: token: '[PII is hidden]'.`

Can you please help here, what is missing below for implicity and token flow. And that leading to above error and white page.

Below is the Auth configuration.

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
             AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = "sub";

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
         CookieHttpOnly = true
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"],
        ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
        ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"],
        RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"],
        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken,
        Scope = "offline_access openid profile",
        RequireHttpsMetadata = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsProduction"]),

        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
           SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                    {
                        var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                        id.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));
                        n.AuthenticationTicket = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket(id, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
            });
        }
```